# Save as value (without formula, macros, password)

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook contains several sheets ,, I want to save this file on daily basis but as values only I tried to use this code however the new generated file ask me for the password "same password of the original file" what should i do to amend this ..

```
Sub SaveAsValues()
Dim ws As Worksheet


For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.UsedRange = ws.UsedRange.Value
Next ws

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "Z:\Collateral Monitoring\Daily\LMM - " & Format(Date, "dd mmmm yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Value = .Value` or more precise `ws2.Range(ws1.UsedRange.Address).Value = ws1.UsedRange.Value`

Comment: Read [This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-or-remove-protection-in-your-document-workbook-or-presentation-05084cc3-300d-4c1a-8416-38d3e37d6826) to learn how to add or remove your password. You can also do a Google search for "How to add and remove excel password.

Comment: Thank you GMalc however i did not say i don't the password (i need it in the original workbook) however i need the new generated workbook to be a free password in order to send it to my customers

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs "Z:\Collateral Monitoring\Daily\LMM - " & Format(Date, "dd mmmm yyyy") _ 
FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```